# How to align text in <p> tag related with tables?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code https://jsfiddle.net/v80btsf4/ with 4 tables ordered in pairs, using 2 `divs`, one for tables on the left and another `div` for tables on the right.

Currently looks like this:
[image]

And I´d like align to the left, the texts above each table and add 2 green bands to right and left (if it is too much complicated, then please help only with the text alignment) in order to look like this:

[image]

In last part of CSS code I've added the `text-align: left;` but doesn´t work.

```
  p {
   font-size : 20px;
   background-color : #cfc;
   padding : 0;
   margin : 0;
   text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: Tables aren't meant for layout, they're meant for tabular data. For grid layout, use `display: grid;` and related. Here's a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and here's a [cheatsheet](https://grid.malven.co/). (Similar situation with `p`, use `div` or `span` for layout as appropriate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove width of `tableWrapperLeft` and `tableWrapperRight` class names and set justify-content `#tableContainer` to `center` also add `margin-right: auto` to `<p>` tags as follows:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

/*  #inputContainer {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
      }*/

#tableContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -25px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tableWrapperLeft {
  margin: 0 25px;
  /*border: 2px solid yellow;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.tableWrapperRight {
  margin: 0 25px;
  /*border: 2px solid yellow;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 288px;
}

td {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  text-align: center;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}

/*tr:first-child td {
        border-top: 1px dotted black;
      }*/

.tableWrapperRight table {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.tableWrapperLeft table {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #cfc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <div class="tableWrapperLeft">
        <p class="text-center">Text 1</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="tableWrapperRight">
        <p>Text 3</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>9</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Text 4</p>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you have any problem with this changes, comment under the answer for me to resolve it.

You can see margin value between two tables [in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXauH.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The text alignment it seems to work fine, but not sure if eliminating width in left and right div makes bigger the central separation between tables. I'd like a fix central separation between tables to for example 25px

Comment: Because there is a margin in the `tableWrapperLeft` and `tableWrapperRight` class names, it resulted in a fixed central separation between the tables. you can use inspect of browser to check margin value between the tables